# How to switch content in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

So I have a main dashboard on my app, in which I have a sidebar navigation and content container. But since I`m new to next.js and unfamiliar with its routing system, I don't know how to implement content changing when a user uses sidebar navigation. Should I make a separate page for each navigation route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for each route your have to create a file in `pages` directory.

- for route `/` you create the file `pages/index.js`
- for route `my-page` you create the file `pages/my-page.js`
- for route `path/my-page` you create the folder `pages/path` and the file `pages/folder/my-file.js`

For more explanation you can read [the documentation of Next.js on routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction).
And you can also follow [the official tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app) to get basic knowledge of Next.js.